# Visual Studio edit override method template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is there any way to change the default override method autogenerated by visual studio? If I implement an abstract class by doing following:

[image: implement abstract class]

Visual Studio generates the following code:

```cs
public override void OverrideMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Can I edit this template, so Visual Studio generates an "normal" method body instead an expression body?

```cs
public override void OverrideMethod() 
{
    throw new NotImplementedException("not implemented");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio under

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General

You can change "Use expression body for methods" to never.

Note that this also changes all of the code generation that would have generated expression bodies such as automatically implementing an interface.

Also, if you have a method that you want to convert from an expression body to a block body, or visa versa, simply press `Ctrl+.` on the method and you will get the quick action to automatically convert it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the offered solution has not worked, because of VS settings were overridden with **.editorconfig** file in the solution. See [Create portable, custom editor settings with EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022)

To fix it I was needed to put to the **.editorconfig** file following line:

`csharp_style_expression_bodied_methods = false`